# Sending Mail using parse-cloud, mailgun and ember.js

Tags: ember.js, parse-platform, mailgun

I am newbie to ember.js and node.I want to send email using mailgun in an ember.js app ,but can't find a way to do that. Found mailgun-js package but do not how to connect this package with ember.js using express. Or if there is any way that i could call a parse-cloud function in ember controller to send mail.

Answer (score 0):

Ember runs in the browser while sending email is done (or: should under most circumstances be done) on the server. `express` and `mailgun-js` hint at that that's what you really want to do (as they are server-side node modules).

You'd have to hook the mail-sending into the REST backend on the server or provide it as an extra service that you might access through a jQuery-Ajax-Call from your ember app.